# Change default schema for user

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

```
create schema bla;

-- then create table table_name into this schema
```

Then I want change default  schema for user (user is `postgres`)

I do:  `ALTER ROLE postgres SET search_path TO bla;` (Query returned successfully with no result).

When I try `SELECT * FROM table_name` gives error `relation "table_name" does not exist`

Though `SELECT * FROM bla.table_name` works fine.

What is wrong in my attempt to change default schema for user?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think you need to relogin for that. With `ALTER USER ... SET` [you change](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-user.html)

> Session defaults for run-time configuration variables

Also from `ALTER ROLE SET` [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterrole.html):

> Role-specific variable settings take effect only at login;

But don't apply changes to current session. If you want immediate change use:

```
SET search_path TO bla;
```

It will change path on session level

Comment: On the linked documentation page, I don't see any reference to

    alter role set search_path to


The "exact" syntax is needed, because the grant seems to execute, but the default schema is not changed.

Answer (score 5):

In PostGres the exact command would be

```
ALTER USER 'your-user' set SEARCH_PATH = 'schema_name';
```