# More efficient way to write a query

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

Here is my working Query :

```
SELECT 
    public."T1"."Id"    AS "StuffId",
    public."T1"."Name"  AS "StuffName",
    public."T3"."Id"    AS "ThingId",
    public."T3"."Name"  AS "ThingName",
    public."T4"."Id"    AS "AnyId",
    public."T4"."Name"  AS "AnyName"
FROM public."T1"
INNER JOIN  public."T2"
    ON public."T1"."Id" = public."T2"."StuffId"
INNER JOIN public."T3"
    ON public."T2"."Id" = public."T2"."ThingId"
INNER JOIN public."T4"
    ON public."T4"."Id" = public."T2"."AnyId"
```

I want to write it in a more readable way with aliases but for the alias is never acknowledge.

I am pretty knew to postgresql but I have a very good knowledge of SQL Server, My SQL and Oracle.

This is what I kinda want :

```
SELECT 
    Stuff.Id    AS "StuffId",
    Stuff.Name  AS "StuffName",
    Thing.Id    AS "ThingId",
    Thing.Name  AS "ThingName",
    Any.Id  AS "AnyId",
    Any.Name    AS "AnyName"
FROM public."T1" AS Stuff
INNER JOIN  public."T2" AS Link
    ON Stuff.Id = Link.StuffId
INNER JOIN public."T3" AS Thing
    ON Thing.Id = Link.ThingId
INNER JOIN public."T4" AS Any
    ON Any.Id = Link.AnyId
```

What should I change in my first query to have something like that?

Comment: "but for the alias is never acknowledge" -- can you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: I mean the second query does not work

Comment: The first thing you could do is omit the `public`, it is the defauilt schema name. Second, you could avoid the `"MixedCaseNames"` so you don't need to quote the identifiers. BTW: `ON public."T2"."Id" = public."T2"."ThingId"` in your first query looks like a typo.

Comment: What do you mean by - you could avoid the "MixedCaseNames"? I can't choose the data table name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you want to do is get rid of all these noisy quotes around identifiers. In standard SQL, identifiers are considered case-insensitive (and default to upper case), so these 3 (unquoted) qualifiers are syntaxically equivalent :

```
... as FOO
... as foo
... as FoO
```

Quoted identifiers are there to be used when mixed cases is really required or when identifiers clash with reserved keywords.

The problem in your use case is that you cannot remove the quotes from your query, because *your tables were initially created with (quoted) camelCase identifiers*, like :

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (
    "Id"    INT,
    "Name"  VARCHAR(100)
);
```

You need to [`RENAME` these columns](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-rename-column/) to something without quotes :

```
ALTER TABLE T1 RENAME "Id" TO id;
ALTER TABLE T1 RENAME "Name" TO name;
```

To replace case breaks in camelCase notation, I would recommend using the underscore character :

```
ALTER TABLE T2 RENAME "StuffId" TO stuff_id;
```

Once all table columns are properly renamed then you can run the following query :

```
SELECT 
    Stuff.Id    AS Stuff_Id,
    Stuff.Name  AS Stuff_Name,
    Thing.Id    AS Thing_Id,
    Thing.Name  AS Thing_Name,
    Any.Id      AS Any_Id,
    Any.Name    AS Any_Name
FROM 
    T1 AS Stuff
    INNER JOIN T2 AS Link ON Stuff.Id = Link.Stuff_Id
    INNER JOIN T3 AS Thing ON Thing.Id = Link.Thing_Id
    INNER JOIN T4 AS Any ON Any.Id = Link.Any_Id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, as the tables were created long before I join this project, I can't be sure but this sounds like a real explanation : "The problem in your use case is that you cannot remove the quotes from your query, because your tables were initially created with (quoted) camelCase identifiers"

Answer (score 0):

The word `public` is [SHEMA](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/ddl-schemas.html) name. If this is default DB schema then you can miss this in queries. Just write like this `T1.Id` it should works fine.

If this schema is not default then you are able to change it for some db user and works with him [Change default schema for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44429178/change-default-schema-for-user)

Comment: Ok, I can go without the word public but I can't write this T1.Id, I can only write "T1"."Id"

Comment: You can but don't use Appendix C. SQL Key Words https://postgrespro.com/docs/postgrespro/9.6/sql-keywords-appendix .

Your current second query have a word Any that is wrong