# Is there any way to access the tables in postgre SQL so that i don't have to use database.table_name everytime while reading a data from a table?

Tags: sql, postgresql-15

I use database.table_name only in Postgre SQL everytime i want to select a data from a table which is slightly annoying. Is there anyway to no use that and still run by queries without error

For ex in postgre SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM database.table_name
```

whereas in mysql:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
```

Haven't tried any different approach

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44429178/change-default-schema-for-user

Comment: Duplicate of [Change default schema for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44429178/change-default-schema-for-user)